# Problem using git on Windows 7 with msysgit and .ssh keys

Tags: windows-7, ssh, git, public-key, msysgit

I'm using git on my Ubuntu machine with my existing ssh keys.

Now I have to use Git on Windows 7, and need to use the same keypairs.
I have set up msysgit and created an `.ssh` folder in `Users\username\.ssh`.
I have copied my keypair from Ubuntu's `.ssh` folder to this folder.

But when I try to clone the Git repo, it stops and asks for the password.
According to some tutorials, I should have some options during the msysgit installation regarding `ssh`, but I saw none.
Do you have any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set your **`HOME`** environment variable to whatever directory you selected for creating the `.ssh` folder (it doesn't have to be necessarily `Users\username\`).

`%HOME%` isn't a native environment variable (`%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` or `%USERPROFILE%` is), and the [mingw Unix-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417) session of msysgit is entirely based on the `$HOME` value.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add this HOME env. variable?

Comment: @Burre: simply define a User environment variable called `HOME` in your Windows settings, like described in http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html.

Comment: HOMEPATH does not suffice, it should either be %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% or %USERPROFILE%

Comment: @bgerth Thank you, I have belatedly edited the answer.